# How to specify spark.authenticate.secret value while executing spark pgm

Tags: apache-spark

I got this error when I launched my spark program with deploy-mode : client.

java.lang.illegalargumentexception: error: a secret key must be specified via the spark.authenticate.secret config.

deploy-mode: client
master: YARN.

How do I resolve this error? I have no clue.

Comment: What is the command you are using to deploy the spark job ?

Comment: I am using spark-submit. deploy mode is client. I got this error when I was trying to set the config properties on sparkconf before passing it to config method while creating SparkSession.

Comment: similor question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50042083/1592191

Answer (score 1):

I got similar error in yarn-cluster mode, following helped me :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23476

If spark.authenticate=true is specified as a cluster wide config, then the following has to be added
--conf "spark.authenticate=false" --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false" --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" --conf "spark.network.crypto.enabled=false" --conf "spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption=false"
in the spark-submit command.